# How to use Tesseract-android-Tools

Tags: android, tesseract

I am having the tesseract-android-tools 1.00, please help me to use the interface TessBaseAPI.

I juss want to pass one .jpg image to an android application which is having some text as a part of image. then through this tesseract engine i want to extract those text into editable format..

please help to create this application in android...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you ever search in the internet for a manual? There are a lot of hints. Recently [someone wrote a small tutorial](http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/).
Even it is for Ubuntu, but I think it gives you a clue how to proceed.

If not, your operating system is needed.

I tried compiling the tesseract-android-tools (tat) with Windows and Cygwin and failed. Some other succeeded. Then after I compiled the tat with the MAC OS and Terminal and succeeded, by using the NDK 5b.

So first have a closer look in the internet and then specify your question, so appropriate help can be posted.

Best wishes,
Volker

Answer (score 2):

I recently used tess-two, which is a fork of tesseract android tools. Step-by-step tutorial on how to setup your development environment, and how to use the library with android, is provided at the readme section here - https://github.com/gorjanz/com-vodi-smetka.android